# Android concurrent file access between 2 apps

Tags: java, android, concurrency, locking

I have 2 applications, one is launched by the other and both need to be able to read and write files in the same directory, and although very rarely, both have tried to read/write the same file concurrently, resulting in a crash (logs have been lost since)

Is there a way sharing a lock between two apps? or is this the default behavior for locks?

Anything I have found regarding locking and android doesn't mention locking between apps only between threads/services in the same app.

Also unsure if this is relevant but this will be a retro fit as the applications were primarily written by someone who either assumed that this concurrency was safe or just ignored it all together.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484182/how-to-lock-a-file-on-different-application-levels